# How to draw triple underlines in Pyqt5 QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

use the following code to draw a double and single underline. If My Shortcut modifier is **"Ctrl"** then a double underline will appear below my text, IF My shortcut modifier is **"**Alt**"** then  a single underline will appear. Now My problem, If my shortcut modifier is a combination of **"Ctrl" + "Alt"**, then a triple underline will appear below my text. How to draw a triple underline ?

```
    ctrl_modifier = """<td style="
                        border-bottom-style: double;
                        border-bottom-width: 3px;
                        border-bottom-color: black;
                        ">%s</td>"""

     alt_modifier = """<td style="
                        border-bottom-style: solid;
                        border-bottom-width: 2px;
                        border-bottom-color: black;
                        ">%s</td>"""

     ....
        self.setText(MyLabel1.ctrl_modifier % "This is my Text")
```

Comment: Assuming `border-bottom-style` to be a CSS property, here are the possible values: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom_style.asp (no triple border/underline).

Comment: There's no triple border style even in standard CSS, and in any case you should always rely on the Qt Rich Text support (which is a *limited* subset of HTML and CSS), which shows [the available CSS properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties): as you can see, the only supported border styles are `none | dotted | dashed | dot-dash | dot-dot-dash | solid | double | groove | ridge | inset | outset`

Comment: By the way, you could try to make the text underlined (`<u></u>`), but it will probably never be properly aligned.